# select2 and Bootstrap not styling input field elements in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, select2-rails

My input fields are not looking like they should, as per http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/#documentation

Not only is the Bootstrap or select2 styling not applying to the input fields, I'm getting some funny duplicate behavior of the labels and forms here.

My unsubstantiated haunch is that Bootstrap isn't being properly registered or communicating with select2.

[image]

app/views/characters/_form.html.haml

```
= form_for(@character, :html => { :multipart => true }) do |f|
    - if @character.errors.any?
        #error_explanation
            %h2= "#{pluralize(@character.errors.count, "error")} prohibited this character from being saved:"
            %ul
                - @character.errors.full_messages.each do |msg|
                    %li= msg

    #stripe_error.alert.alert-danger{ :style => "display:none" }
        %noscript JavaScript is not enabled and is required for this form. First enable it in your web browser settings.

    .form-group
        = f.label :name
        = f.text_field :name, autofocus: true
    .form-group
        = f.label :image
        = f.file_field :image
    .form-group
        = f.label :universe_ids, "Link Universes"
        = f.collection_select :universe_ids, Universe.order(:name), :id, :name, {}, {multiple: true}  # Getting a lot of funny behavior with these lines            
    .action
        = f.submit
```

characters.js.coffee

```
jQuery ->
  $("#character_universe_ids").select2(
    placeholder: "Pick a Universe");
```

application.js

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery.turbolinks
//= require jquery_ujs
//
//= require bootstrap
//= require select2
//
//= require_self
//= require_tree .
//= require turbolinks
```

application.css.scss

```
@import "resets";
@import "bootstrap";
@import "custom/cp_variables";
@import "custom/cp_custom";
@import "custom/cp_responsive";

/*
 *= require select2
 *= require select2-bootstrap
 *
 *= require_self
 *= require_tree .
 */
```

How would I be able to tell if the `*= select2-bootstrap` line is working properly?
I am using `bootstrap-sass` gem, not a copied library in the vendor assets folder.

gemfile

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

ruby "2.0.0"

gem 'rails', '4.0.0'

gem 'haml-rails', '0.5.1'
gem 'html2haml', '~> 1.0.1'

gem 'sass-rails', '~> 4.0.0'
gem 'autoprefixer-rails'
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 3.1.1'

gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.0.0'
gem 'jquery-rails'

gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
gem 'turbolinks', '~>2.2.2'
gem 'jquery-turbolinks', '~>2.0.2'
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 1.2'
gem 'sprockets-rails', :require => 'sprockets/railtie'

gem 'pg', '0.17.1'

group :doc do
  # bundle exec rake doc:rails generates the API under doc/api.
  gem 'sdoc', require: false
end


gem 'nokogiri', '~> 1.6.0'
# Secret keys.
gem 'figaro', '~> 0.7.0'
# Images.
gem 'paperclip', '~> 3.0'
# Image storage.
gem 'paperclip-dropbox', '>= 1.1.7'
# Authentication.
gem 'devise'#, '3.2.3'
# Votes.
gem 'acts_as_votable', '~> 0.9.0'
# Autocomplete form.
gem 'select2-rails'

group :development do
    # For html2haml mass conversion
    # erubis is already included in action pack
    gem 'ruby_parser', '~> 3.1.1'
end

group :test do

end

group :production do
  gem 'rails_12factor', '0.0.2'

  #gem 'aws-sdk', "~> 1.0"
end


# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt-ruby', '~> 3.0.0'

# Use unicorn as the app server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano', group: :development

# Use debugger
# gem 'debugger', group: [:development, :test]
```

I couldn't find any threads  of people having this problem. All the tutorials simply say to apply the simple `.select2()` method to the proper DOM element, but I'm simply not getting the styling that I should be getting.